# WDA Connection Time Out with Appium 1.10.0 & IOS (12.1.2)

Tags: ios, xcode, appium-ios

Please , I need your help about one problem :

I obtain this message error with appium "WDA connection timeout" when I launched my tests automated from IPhone 6+ with version system (12.1.2) . I use XCode 10.1 and the WebDriverAgent is installed with success on my IPhone.I join you a part of logs Appium :

```
[XCUITest] Connection to WDA timed out
[iProxy] recv failed: Operation not permitted
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/117cd327-7c9e-4888-971e-76b6c4c25237/timeouts
[HTTP] {"implicit":80000}
[W3C (117cd327)] Calling AppiumDriver.timeouts() with args: [null,null,null,null,80000,"117cd327-7c9e-4888-971e-76b6c4c25237"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'timeouts'
[BaseDriver] W3C timeout argument: {"implicit":80000}}
[BaseDriver] Set implicit wait to 80000ms
[W3C (117cd327)] Responding to client with driver.timeouts() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/117cd327-7c9e-4888-971e-76b6c4c25237/timeouts 200 3 ms - 14
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/117cd327-7c9e-4888-971e-76b6c4c25237/timeouts
[HTTP] {"implicit":300000}
[W3C (117cd327)] Calling AppiumDriver.timeouts() with args: [null,null,null,null,300000,"117cd327-7c9e-4888-971e-76b6c4c25237"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'timeouts'
[BaseDriver] W3C timeout argument: {"implicit":300000}}
[BaseDriver] Set implicit wait to 300000ms
[W3C (117cd327)] Responding to client with driver.timeouts() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/117cd327-7c9e-4888-971e-76b6c4c25237/timeouts 200 3 ms - 14
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/117cd327-7c9e-4888-971e-76b6c4c25237/touch/perform
[HTTP] {"actions":[{"action":"tap","options":{"x":220,"y":417}}]}
[W3C (117cd327)] Calling AppiumDriver.performTouch() with args: [[{"action":"tap","options":{"x":220,"y":417}}],"117cd327-7c9e-4888-971e-76b6c4c25237"]
```

and :

```
[XCUITest] WebDriverAgent information:
[XCUITest] {
[XCUITest] "state": "success",
[XCUITest] "os": {
[XCUITest] "name": "iOS",
[XCUITest] "version": "12.1.2"
[XCUITest] },
[XCUITest] "ios": {
[XCUITest] "simulatorVersion": "12.1.2",
[XCUITest] "ip": null
[XCUITest] },
[XCUITest] "build": {
[XCUITest] "time": "Jan 30 2019 12:28:16"
[XCUITest] }
```

Before, I haven't this problem because I used XCode 9.2 and appium 1.7 and version system ios (11.2.6).

I had read many answers for other problems that like the mine but I didn't find the solution.

Thank you very much in Advance,

Best Regards,